# WPF: Clickable button in ItemTemplate of a ComboBoxItem with IsEnabled=false

Tags: c#, wpf

Trying to set up a WPF `ComboBox`;
some of its items should not be selectable, so I'm binding `IsEnabled` to some property of the underlying item.

At the same time, I need to define an `ItemTemplate` that contains e.g. a Button.
This button needs to be clickable, even if the item is not selectable (worth nothing a click on the button should not select the item as such of course; it will trigger a command performing some background actions, which will eventually make the underlying item selectable)

However, when `ComboBoxItem.IsEnabled = false`, it seems even the button automatically gets disabled.

Brief example:

```
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding CanSelectItem}"/>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>

                    <!-- This button isn't clickable when ComboBoxItem.IsEnabled = false .. but it should be! -->
                    <Button Content="Click me" Command="{Binding SomeCmd}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

Is there any way to circumvent this? E.g., set some items as non-selectable, however define a button in the `ItemTemplate` that remains clickable regardless?

Thanks

Comment: Setting the ComboBoxItem as disabled will disable _all_ of its content. Maybe instead of disabling just cancel the `SelectionChanged` event when suitable?

Answer (score 1):

When you remove the `ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle` you can set the `IsEnabled` property of each element in the `DataTemplate`

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                       IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.IsEnabled}"/>
            <Button Content="Click me" Command="{Binding SomeCmd}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

The combobox item will still be enabled but the `TextBlock` will be disabled.
The binding is just an example. Depends on where your `IsEnabled` property is. In my example the property is in the viewmodel which is `DataContext` of your `Window`.

Comment: Won't this allow for the item to be selected (regardless of the `TextBlock`'s status as disabled)? I can't test right now, thanks.

Comment: @nondestructive Damn, yes...good point. As far as I know there is no other way to enable the button; as you mentioned in the other comment.

Comment: Well, your answer could still be useful if that event suggestion is viable. You'd still want the text to be (or at least look) disabled.

Comment: @nondestructive Yes, that's why I did not deleted the answer. Maybe it still does what the questioneer wants.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! Have the (probably useless) habit of trying to avoid codebehind in the view where possible, but seeing this seems to be the best - or only - way in this case, will go for the ideas you suggested. Thanks

Comment: @Bogey Glad to help. I'd argue that avoiding code-behind in views is a problem only when it becomes counter-productive (i.e. you end up spending more time/resources in figuring out how to avoid it than on _actually_ solving the problem).

Comment: True - probably just a bad habit on my end. Have played around with the solution a bit, it works well but does allow to "fake select" disabled items (e.g. clicking on them will close the combobox), also think the SelectedItem will actually change for a brief moment before canceling. Looking at a second way (posted below) by using a custom button with custom IsEnabled-behavior; not quite sure yet which one is going to be the better way

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, have found another way of doing this, based on this answer:

[WPF override IsEnabled from Parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22248943/wpf-override-isenabled-from-parent)

So basically creating a class derived from button that overrides the default IsEnabled behavior.

Benefit is that this seems to do exactly what I was looking for, but it does change one of WPF's pretty.. default behaviors, so might need to be taken with a bit of care